# Can not use Pi Camera Module 3 (IMX708) with RaspberryPi 4B (4GB) - Raspbian (bullseye)

Tags: raspberry-pi, picamera

I am trying to use the Pi Camera Module 3 on the Raspberry Pi 4B. I have tried running a Python script which calls the module in the terminal, and the output shows an error message:

```
cshwstem@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 preview.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cshwstem/Desktop/preview.py", line 18, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from picamera.exc import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import picamera.mmal as mmal
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmal.py", line 49, in <module>
    _lib = ct.CDLL('libmmal.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone encountered this error before when using the Pi Camera Module 3 on the Raspberry Pi 4?